# having to cmd in one command prompt

Tags: command-prompt

how would one want invoke another instance of the command prompt and make it run within the current command prompt window. ive tried using start command prompt but it would just make another application. I want to have one build in the same command prompt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `cmd` it will create another instance of command prompt within the command prompt you are calling it from.

This will effectively run a new instance of command prompt inside the current instance, this way you could potentially run a command prompt inside a command prompt inside a command prompt inside ...